# unit test in python for function that has no return value

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing

I have a function that should pick only top 10 requests from list of requests:

```
def prioritize_top_10_requests(list_of_requests):
if not list_of_requests:
    system.exit(1)
else:
    for i in list_of_requests[0:10]:
        print i
```

I want to write a unit test for this function just to check if 'i' is printed 10 times only though we have more list of requests.

I am writing python unit test cases for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have python3 set up. The below code works with Python 3.

What it does is the following.

- Created a UnitTest TestCase with one test, "test_priority".
- In the test, redirect the stdout to a string.
- Then execute the function.
- Collect the print results from the string.
- Remove None and empty strings and find the length.
- Check if it is equal to 10.

```
import unittest
from io import StringIO
import sys

def prioritize_top_10_requests(list_of_requests):
    for i in list_of_requests[0:10]:
        print(i)

class TestMyCode(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_priority(self):
        sys.stdout = result = StringIO()
        prioritize_top_10_requests(range(100))
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
        printed_lines = result.getvalue()
        print_count = len(printed_lines.strip().split('\n'))
        self.assertEqual(print_count, 10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```